# redis: pop from list of not empty, return random element of other list otherwise

Tags: redis

There are two lists in redis, having keys *l1* and *l2*. *l2* is guaranteed to not be empty. I want to pop (read and remove) the first element of *l1*, if it is not empty, and otherwise return a random element from *l2* without removing it.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior without requiring any client-side technology, framework, logic or an additional roundtrip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lpop on l1 and if no element is returned then lpop on l2 - and you put these in a lua script, so you don't have any additional roundtrip:

```
local redis_list_member = redis.call('lpop', KEYS[1])
if not redis_list_member then 
    redis_list_member = redis.call('lpop', KEYS[2])
end
return redis_list_member
```

And with [eval](http://redis.io/commands/eval) you can pass the script to redis with the 2 lists as parameters

Comment: Exactly, although a generic version of the script is always preferable

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by Liviu, so this is basically the same script but for any number of lists provided as input via the `KEYS` table:

```
for _, k in pairs(KEYS) do
  local m = redis.call('LPOP', k)
  if m then
    return m
  end
end
```